# Why are Moufang loops important?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

Groups are important because they can describe symmetries. Why are Moufang loops important? I feel that the four identities are simply arbitrary.

Comment: I'm not an expert here so this is just a comment, but one starting point (for me at least) is that lots of structures related to the octonions form Moufang loops instead of groups. For example, the 7-sphere of unit octonions under multiplication is a Moufang loop but not a group (there are other examples). In general, my impression is that various not-too-nonassociative structures arising naturally wind up being Moufang loops or being related to Moufang loops.